# How to block all access to Akami deploy servers and Apple push servers?

Tags: firewalls, data-leakage, macos, spyware

I no longer blindly trust the numerous connections that occur at night and during the day that always go to "content" and "push" servers like:

```
a23-33-37-54.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com
st11p01st-courier001-bz.push.apple.com
ve-in-f113.1e100.net
```

These always happen at night when no one is using the computer. I do not have iCloud enabled.

So I would like to block these. Is there an effective way to do that?

I tried setting these as keywords to block in my wifi router that that doesn't seem to work, perhaps because these sites are not being accessed by a browser.

```
 127.0.0.1 1e100.net
```

However this will not block direct access to an IP address e.g. https get from 173.194.75.113:443.

How can I block an IP range?

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of Akamai / Apple push servers. You'd need a hosts entry for _each_. You're better off with a firewall that can block by wildcard, e.g. `*.deploy.akamaitechnologies`. With a decent firewall you should also be able to set additional rule options, such as the time ranges that they're enabled.

Comment: Right but this line added to /etc/hosts should also work: 127.0.0.1 deploy.akamaitechnologies.com.

Comment: It won't, since it'll only prevent you from resolving that *specific* server, rather than subdomains. For example, adding `127.0.0.1 google.com` to `/etc/hosts` doesn't block `mail.google.com`.

Comment: It appears ipfw is still included with OS/X, so I'll use that. But it's deprecated.

Comment: Also, oddly enough the firewall rule for Apple's push server is being ignored...

Comment: I simply uninstalled "Apple Application Support" and the hundreds of connections disappeared. -D
Windows7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Use [LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to restrict what services applications can access, without having to manually list the thousands of servers owned by each of these CDNs. As a bonus, you can specify the rules by application, allowing for a much greater degree of control over who uses what.

Comment: How can I trust that LittleSnitch does not contain spyware?